# As with Vertex uniting facets?

Tags: python, 3d, decode

I have a "hidden" file and transforming it to stl, I want to manually re-engineering to create software that can do it with any file

**STL BASE**

```
facet normal -7.028554081916809e-1 -6.662387847900391e-1 2.4923914670944214e-1
  outer loop
    vertex -1.3733810424804688e+1 -2.2234020233154297e+1 8.85525131225586e+0
    vertex -1.3620129585266113e+1 -2.2398649215698242e+1 8.735763549804688e+0
    vertex -1.356096076965332e+1 -2.2442123413085938e+1 8.786409378051758e+0
  endloop
endfacet
```

The encrypted file will succeed to:

1. Texture (PNG)
2. Vertex (STL)
3. Facets (BINARY application/octet-stream)
4. FacetMarks (STL)
5. Two Matrix4x4 (ARRAY)
6. Per Vertex Texture Coord (BINARY application/octet-stream)

**Vertex:**

```
facet normal 1.3868725048266996e-28 -7.152297857163422e+24 -9.427265167236328e+0
  outer loop
    vertex -1.2666171280220628e-12 3.780374058237612e-8 -7.009968757629395e-1
    vertex 1.7022672896e+10 -8.481494881276995e-39 9.942446044350513e+18
    vertex 7.55889375e+4 1.17091516416e+11 -1.1634081566794228e-33
  endloop
endfacet
```

**FacetMarks:**

```
facet normal inf inf inf
  outer loop
    vertex 1.47009e-39 1.47009e-39 7.17465e-43
    vertex 7.17465e-43 7.17465e-43 7.17465e-43
    vertex 7.17465e-43 7.17465e-43 7.17465e-43
  endloop
endfacet
```

**Header Facets: (HEX)**

```
0000-0010:  04 00 03 00-01 00 03 00-00 00 03 03-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0020:  01 00 03 03-00 02 02 00-00 00 00 00-03 09 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0030:  00 00 01 02-00 01 00 00-00 01 03 03-09 00 01 00  ........ ........
```

**Header Per Vertex Texture Coord: (HEX)**

```
0000-0010:  04 02 73 2b-ca 41 6b 0f-13 17 cf 02-c8 43 29 35  ..s+.Ak. .....C)5
0000-0020:  7f c6 f0 58-c6 5f 66 ef-32 ce 2d 1e-d3 b3 ba 8b  ...X._f. 2.-.....
0000-0030:  e6 e1 14 ec-66 f6 c2 3e-64 e0 48 2f-ba d0 92 ab  ....f..> d.H/....
```

**Two Matrix4x4**

```
//Focus2FinalTrans
var identityMatrix0 = [
  [-0.139106587, -0.9896074,    0.0364231542, 22.71722],
  [ 0.9774915,   -0.143108979, -0.155016765,  -3.1819346],
  [ 0.1586182,    0.01403947,   0.9872402,   -16.35489],
  [ 0            ,0          ,  0        ,     1]
];

//AlignToBiteTransformation
var identityMatrix = [
  [-0.9909725,   8.663357E-8,     0.134065166,   7.589744],
  [-8.742278E-8, -1,             -7.203359E-17, -1.193707],
  [0.134065166,  -1.17203491E-8,  0.9909725,    -1.02678967],
  [0,             0,              0,             1]
];
```

I can not understand how to take all that I have obtained the encrypted file to obtain the same result as the **STL BASE**

I tried with:

```
function multiplyMatrixAndPoint(matrix, point) {
    var c0r0 = matrix[ 0], c1r0 = matrix[ 1], c2r0 = matrix[ 2], c3r0 = matrix[ 3];
    var c0r1 = matrix[ 4], c1r1 = matrix[ 5], c2r1 = matrix[ 6], c3r1 = matrix[ 7];
    var c0r2 = matrix[ 8], c1r2 = matrix[ 9], c2r2 = matrix[10], c3r2 = matrix[11];
    var c0r3 = matrix[12], c1r3 = matrix[13], c2r3 = matrix[14], c3r3 = matrix[15];
    var x = point[0];
    var y = point[1];
    var z = point[2];
    var w = point[3];
    var resultX = (x * c0r0) + (y * c0r1) + (z * c0r2) + (w * c0r3);
    var resultY = (x * c1r0) + (y * c1r1) + (z * c1r2) + (w * c1r3);
    var resultZ = (x * c2r0) + (y * c2r1) + (z * c2r2) + (w * c2r3);
    var resultW = (x * c3r0) + (y * c3r1) + (z * c3r2) + (w * c3r3);
    return [resultX, resultY, resultZ, resultW]
}
```

and...

```
var transform = function(point,vector){
  var p = [0,0,0];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    p[i] += vector[i][3];
    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
       p[i] += point[c] * vector[i][c];
     }; 
  };
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to recreate STLbase after decrypting your file?

Comment: You can post encrypt, decrypt function code+(error,warnings) so that it will be easy to identify if anything is going wrong during decryption.